# Creating a Python Function to Use a JSON Data Feed and Launch API Search

Tags: python, json, function, api

I'm not entirely sure if I know how to ask this question but below is my goal:

I have a Python package installed on my machine that searches for data online and returns URLs to download. I would like to create a separate Python function that passes the search parameters from a JSON data feed, launches the package (importing the necessary library, identify the configuration file, performs the search, and prints the URLs), and then returns the printed URLs. I admittedly am not completely sure how to get started or really if my question makes sense.

Typically, I use the search API through a console or cmd line and have no problems with the steps mentioned above (importing library, defining .cfg, searching, and printing URLs. Just don't know the procedure for making an "automated" function to perform this in the background. Thanks in advance for the help. Am happy to clarify any details if need be.

-Respectfully, 
C

Answer (score 1):

Start with a single search step that "launches the package". It could be a function or even a separate complete Python script. Let's call it `do_search`. It's self-contained, can be tested independently, and can can be built upon.

Create a function that accepts a record from a data feed, prepares the data for the `search` function / script, launches it (maybe via `subprocess.Popen`), and collects the result. Let's call it `invoke_search`.

Create a function / script that keeps reading from a data feed. It can call `invoke_search` on each new coming item, or run a reasonable number of `invoke_search` in parallel (using a thread pool, a process pool, or maybe celery), and offer some kind of data sink / stream to write the search results to.

Typically you provide two pipes: for tasks and for results. Your feed-reading process reads from a feed and puts items from the feed into the task pipe. Your worker threads / processes read from the task pipe. A worker waits for and then picks a task from the task pipe, does its work, and pushes the result to the results pipe.

Your results pipe can be anything; it could put data to a file, or a directory, to a database, etc.

If your feed refreshes slowly and parallel processing gives no benefit, you can do all this sequentially, but the general architecture holds.

Comment: Thanks for the response. On my end, I am only needing to do the first two steps you described. I believe the architecture to perform background processing is already in place with Celery. At this point, I simply need to launch the package, accept the JSON data feed coming in, apply those parameters to the search, and return the resulting URLs. I haven't messed around with subprocess management or launching packages/external scripts before but it sounds like those two functions can be contained in one script (do_search)? Sequentially: do_search then invoke search?

Comment: Presumably, since the package is installed could I simply import the necessary modules from the package and have only one function that parses the json feed to apply the search parameters?

Comment: @CaseyC: most likely! Try doing this and see if it works.

Comment: Will do! Will respond to this this afternoon with update. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There's a little bit of front end work left but for the most part this is a decent stand alone script. Thanks for the help 9000!

```
from pyCMR import CMR

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json 

cmr=CMR(".../cmr.cfg")    

def search (dt, pt, short):

    search = cmr.searchGranule(temporal=dt, point=pt, short_name=short)

    return search;

with open('jsontest.txt','r') as job:
        data=json.load(job)
        print data

dt = data['start']+", "+data['end']
print dt
pt = data['point']
short = data['short_name']

res= search(dt=dt,pt=pt,short=short)
for result in res:
    print result['Granule']['OnlineAccessURLs']['OnlineAccessURL']['URL']
```